# NPM Package.json main property pointing to a hash file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

With `webpack` it is possible to append a `hash` to your built source and have an `assets.json` that points to the hashed file.

Is it possible to leverage `package.json`'s `main` prop to somehow point to `assets.json` so that I can build libraries where the filename has a hash?

Comment: It's been 5 years late, but I am curious on this answer too.